# Quarto: PDF Document - Figure Caption size

Tags: pdf, latex, r-markdown, quarto

How to customize font size of **Figure Caption** in a quarto pdf document? I have checked about the  `mainfont` and `fontfamily` options, but the documentation doesn't provide examples of how to use change the font size for individual elements in a pdf document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since for pdf output, ultimately latex is used, you just need to find the corresponding latex solution to do what you want to do and incorporate those latex codes using [`LaTex Includes`](https://quarto.org/docs/output-formats/pdf-basics.html#latex-includes).

So to change the figure caption size, we can use the [`caption`](https://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption.pdf) package. From section 2.3 of the `caption` package manual,

> There are three font options which affect different parts of the caption: One affecting the whole caption (`font`), one which only affects the caption label and separator (`labelfont`) and at least one which only affects the caption text (`textfont`).

> You set them up using the options `font={⟨font options⟩}`, `labelfont={⟨font options⟩}`, and `textfont={⟨font options⟩}`, where ⟨font options⟩ is a list of comma separated font options.

And these are the available font options:

- `scriptsize` => Very small size
- `footnotesize` => The size usually used for footnotes
- `small` => Small size
- `normalsize` => Normal size
- `large` => Large size
- `Large` => Even larger size

Read the manual (section 2.3) to know the details and more options.

---

````
---
title: "Figure Caption Size"
format: 
  pdf:
    include-in-header:
      text: |
       \usepackage[font=Large,labelfont={bf,Large}]{caption}
---

## Quarto

```{r}
#| fig-cap: "Just a scatterplot"

plot(rnorm(1:10), rnorm(1:10))
```
````

---

[image: Large caption for figure in Quarto]

---